# Get DbId's of all the nested family in autodesk forge form RVT file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using **tree.enumNodeChildren** to get the child dbids in the viewer.

```
function getAllLeafComponents() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            viewer.getObjectTree(function (tree) {
                var leaves = [];
                tree.enumNodeChildren(tree.getRootId(), function (dbId) {
                    if (tree.getChildCount(dbId) === 0) {
                        leaves.push(dbId);
                    }
                }, true);
                resolve(leaves)
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```

I am getting all the Ids but i am not getting the Dbid's for the Nested family which is in the revit file.

I have a host family in revit , which has a family component inserted with the shared parameter enabled. When we want to get the dbids of the nested family, only the dbids of the family which are inserted into the host family are coming. The host family dbid is not received. We have tested with many nested families with both shared parameters enabled and not enabled still the dbids are not coming. How to fix this issue. What will be the solution?

I used the code which i have given above and got the children nodes and i want all the nodes which are present in the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

By default, objects in the nested family will be merged into one object during the translation. So, you cannot select individual objects within the nested family in the viewer.

If you want to make them selectable individually, you must enable the "Shared" option on the nested family, not the top family. https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-32FD07FC-7CB2-45FD-8279-702D5013E4C0

Afterward, you can get the properties as usual objects.

```js
let dbId = viewer.getSelection()[0];

viewer.getProperties( dbId, console.log );
```

[image]
[image]